# Параллельная обработка событий

Tags: c#, .net, события

Есть 2 таймера:

1. Срабатывает каждые 5 минут
2. Срабатывает каждые 10 минут

На эти таймеры подписано по одному обработчику, а в каждом обработчике вызывается некий метод.

Как исключить такую ситуацию, когда выполняется обработчик первого таймера и срабатывает событие от второго таймера и из-за этого прерывается обработка первого таймера? Т.е события могут наступать от другого таймера, до обработки текущего таймера, но их обработка не должны прерывать друг друга.

Comment: Что значит `но их обработка не должны прерывать друг друга` . Таймер запускает метод-обработчик в новом потоке, следовательно методы-обработчики разных таймеров не должны мешать друг-другу, так как выполняются в разных потоках. Или у Вас из этих методов идет доступ к совместным ресурсам?

Comment: @sp7, вот оно как. Спасибо

Comment: Если помогло, могу оформить в виде ответа )

Comment: WinForm-овский таймер, вроде как выполняет метод в UI потоке, т.к. остается возможность работать с элементами формы, но я не уверен, надо проверить по исходникам. Даже если так, то можно заменить их на стандартные таймеры, которые точно работают в отдельных потоках.

Comment: Похоже что я прав, исходников Windows.Form.Timer микрососфт не опубликовал но в MSDN нашлась заметка к System.Timers.Timer "The server-based System.Timers.Timer class is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to handle the raised E:System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed event, resulting in more accuracy than Windows timers in raising the event on time."

Comment: @sp7 оформляйте ответ.

Comment: @rdorn: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Timer.cs,21e9545cfe31887d и вообще http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=class%20Timer

Comment: @VladD блин, а я там не нашел, мне вообще в списке пространств имен Windows.Forms отказались показывать =(

Comment: @rdorn: Может, у них баг, или они не любят ваш браузер?

Comment: @VladD может и баг, в дереве пространств имен реально не показывают, только поиском выйти можно, странно. Но толку от о этих исходников по вопросу все одно мало - сам таймер у них в нативном коде, в управляемом только оболочка...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таймер запускает метод-обработчик в новом потоке, следовательно методы-обработчики разных таймеров не должны мешать друг-другу, так как выполняются в разных потоках.

Comment: Ээээ... Вы уверены, что каждый таймер заводит свой отдельный поток?

Comment: @VladD System.Timers.Timer - да, каждый выполняет приписанные ему методы в отдельном потоке

Comment: @VladD System.Timers.Timer - это обертка вокруг таймеров ядра, они сигналят асинхронно. Потоки создаются только для выполнения колбэков, максимально лениво. Поэтому можно создавать много таймеров, и это не скажется на производительности.

Answer (score 10):

Это зависит от того, каким таймером вы пользуетесь. В BCL есть целый зоопарк различных таймеров, у каждого из них своё поведение. Давайте пройдёмся по ним.

1) [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7). Он генерирует свои события в потоке, в который его приводит [`SynchronizingObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject?view=netframework-4.7#System_Timers_Timer_SynchronizingObject). Если вы не устанавливаете этот самый синхронизирующий объект, то обработчики событий выполняются на пуле потоков и, конечно, могут перекрываться. Тестовая программа (#1):

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
int no = 0;
timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
    {
        int local = Interlocked.Increment(ref no);
        Console.WriteLine($"Raised #{local} at {e.SignalTime:mm:ss.fff}," +
            $" started processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}," +
            $" thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine($"#{local} finished processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    };
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

производит результат:

```
Raised #1 at 44:03.992, started processing at 44:03.998, thread #4
Raised #2 at 44:04.997, started processing at 44:04.997, thread #5
Raised #3 at 44:06.001, started processing at 44:06.001, thread #6
#1 finished processing at 44:06.999
Raised #4 at 44:07.002, started processing at 44:07.002, thread #4
#2 finished processing at 44:07.999
Raised #5 at 44:08.003, started processing at 44:08.003, thread #5
#3 finished processing at 44:09.002
Raised #6 at 44:09.003, started processing at 44:09.003, thread #6
#4 finished processing at 44:10.003
Raised #7 at 44:10.007, started processing at 44:10.007, thread #7
#5 finished processing at 44:11.003
Raised #8 at 44:11.012, started processing at 44:11.012, thread #8
#6 finished processing at 44:12.004
Raised #9 at 44:12.013, started processing at 44:12.013, thread #5
#7 finished processing at 44:13.008
Raised #10 at 44:13.014, started processing at 44:13.014, thread #6
#8 finished processing at 44:14.013
Raised #11 at 44:14.015, started processing at 44:14.015, thread #7
#9 finished processing at 44:15.014
Raised #12 at 44:15.016, started processing at 44:15.016, thread #8
```

Мы видим, что для отправления события используется свободный поток из пула, и если обработчики событий медленные, каждый раз будет использован новый поток.

Если у вас *несколько подписок* на событие от таймера, то все они будут вызваны **последовательно** в одном потоке (возможно, своём потоке для каждого из событий). Это приведёт к тому, что соседние события обрабатываются параллельно, а соседние *обработчики* — последовательно.
Тестируем (#2):

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
Dictionary<DateTime, int> eventNum = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

void Handler(int hdlr, DateTime eventTime)
{
    int num;
    lock (eventNum) { if (!eventNum.TryGetValue(eventTime, out num))
            eventNum.Add(eventTime, num = eventNum.Values.DefaultIfEmpty().Max() + 1); }
    Console.WriteLine($"[{hdlr}] Raised #{num} at {eventTime:mm:ss.fff}," +
        $" started processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}," +
        $" thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{hdlr}] #{num} finished processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
}

timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => Handler(1, e.SignalTime);
timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => Handler(2, e.SignalTime);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Результат:

```
[1] Raised #1 at 15:17.674, started processing at 15:17.713, thread #4
[1] Raised #2 at 15:18.678, started processing at 15:18.678, thread #5
[1] Raised #3 at 15:19.681, started processing at 15:19.681, thread #6
[1] Raised #4 at 15:20.685, started processing at 15:20.686, thread #7
[1] #1 finished processing at 15:20.714
[2] Raised #1 at 15:17.674, started processing at 15:20.714, thread #4
[1] #2 finished processing at 15:21.679
[2] Raised #2 at 15:18.678, started processing at 15:21.679, thread #5
[1] Raised #5 at 15:21.687, started processing at 15:21.687, thread #8
[1] #3 finished processing at 15:22.682
[2] Raised #3 at 15:19.681, started processing at 15:22.682, thread #6
[1] Raised #6 at 15:22.691, started processing at 15:22.691, thread #9
[1] #4 finished processing at 15:23.687
[2] Raised #4 at 15:20.685, started processing at 15:23.687, thread #7
[1] Raised #7 at 15:23.695, started processing at 15:23.695, thread #10
[2] #1 finished processing at 15:23.715
[2] #2 finished processing at 15:24.680
[1] #5 finished processing at 15:24.688
[2] Raised #5 at 15:21.687, started processing at 15:24.688, thread #8
[1] Raised #8 at 15:24.698, started processing at 15:24.698, thread #11
[2] #3 finished processing at 15:25.683
[1] #6 finished processing at 15:25.691
[2] Raised #6 at 15:22.691, started processing at 15:25.691, thread #9
[1] Raised #9 at 15:25.699, started processing at 15:25.699, thread #4
```

Если вы установите `SynchronizingObject`, то события будут доставляться ему, и будут вызываться в его контексте. Нужный объект типа `ISynchronizeInvoke` можно найти в WinForms: там каждый контрол имплементирует этот интерфейс. Поэтому в WinForms-приложении в контексте UI-контрола вы можете сказать просто `timer.SynchronizingObject = this;`, и все события будут доставляться в UI-поток. При этом события будут просто добавляться в очередь, ожидающую обработки в UI-потоке. Код (#3)

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
int no = 0;
timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
{
    int local = no++;
    Console.WriteLine($"Raised #{local} at {e.SignalTime:mm:ss.fff}," +
        $" started processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}," +
        $" thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    Thread.Sleep(3000); // тут длинные вычисления
    Console.WriteLine($"#{local} finished processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
};
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

производит результат:

```
Raised #0 at 49:30.805, started processing at 49:30.816, thread #1
#0 finished processing at 49:33.818
Raised #1 at 49:31.805, started processing at 49:33.818, thread #1
#1 finished processing at 49:36.818
Raised #2 at 49:32.806, started processing at 49:36.818, thread #1
#2 finished processing at 49:39.819
Raised #3 at 49:33.809, started processing at 49:39.819, thread #1
#3 finished processing at 49:42.820
Raised #4 at 49:34.809, started processing at 49:42.820, thread #1
```

Вы видите, что события отправляются честно каждую секунду, но поскольку у вас в UI-потоке длинные вычисления (что само по себе плохо), то каждое новое событие начинает работать лишь после окончания предыдущего (то есть, каждые 3 секунды). При этом запросы на обработку накапливаются в очереди, и рано или поздно могут её исчерпать.

Кроме того, проводить длительную синхронную обработку в UI-потоке нехорошо, мы «вешаем» наше приложение. Если мы превратим код в асинхронный (в нашем примере — заменим `Thread.Sleep` на `await Task.Delay` и добавим `async` к обработчику `timer.Elapsed`, то UI, конечно, разблокируется, но во время `await`'а сможет запуститься следующий обработчик, и мы получаем почти такую же картину с перекрытиями, как и в случаем без `SynchronizingObject` (но с работой в одном потоке) (#4):

```
Raised #1 at 11:37.943, started processing at 11:37.943, thread #1
Raised #2 at 11:38.944, started processing at 11:38.944, thread #1
Raised #3 at 11:39.946, started processing at 11:39.947, thread #1
#0 finished processing at 11:39.962
#1 finished processing at 11:40.943
Raised #4 at 11:40.952, started processing at 11:40.952, thread #1
#2 finished processing at 11:41.956
Raised #5 at 11:41.956, started processing at 11:41.956, thread #1
#3 finished processing at 11:42.956
Raised #6 at 11:42.956, started processing at 11:42.956, thread #1
#4 finished processing at 11:43.953
```

Для использования в WPF можно написать свою обёртку на `Dispatcher`, реализующую `ISynchronizeInvoke`, это по идее несложно.

(Обращение к `SynchronizingObject` происходит на пуле потоков, так что даже если вы напишете сумасшедшую реализацию `ISynchronizeInvoke`, которая на запрос `InvokeRequired` всегда возвращает `true`, ваши события будут доставляться в потоки из пула, и не будут мешать друг другу.)

Что же произойдёт, если в пуле нет свободных потоков, и таймеру негде выполнить событие? В этом случае вызов таймера будет отложен (а также последующие вызовы) до момента освобождение пула потоков. Вот эксперимент на четырёхядерной машине (#5):

```
if (!ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4))
    throw new Exception("oops");

var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
int no = 0;

void Handler(int hdlr, DateTime eventTime)
{
    int num = Interlocked.Increment(ref no);
    Console.WriteLine($"Raised #{num} at {eventTime:mm:ss.fff}," +
        $" started processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}," +
        $" thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{hdlr}] #{num} finished processing at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
}

timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => Handler(1, e.SignalTime);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Это производит такой вывод:

```
Raised #1 at 56:08.458, started processing at 56:08.499, thread #4
Raised #2 at 56:09.463, started processing at 56:09.463, thread #5
Raised #3 at 56:10.465, started processing at 56:10.465, thread #6
Raised #4 at 56:11.471, started processing at 56:11.475, thread #7
#1 finished processing at 56:28.501
Raised #5 at 56:28.501, started processing at 56:28.501, thread #4
#2 finished processing at 56:29.465
Raised #6 at 56:29.502, started processing at 56:29.502, thread #5
#3 finished processing at 56:30.466
Raised #7 at 56:30.502, started processing at 56:30.502, thread #6
#4 finished processing at 56:31.475
Raised #8 at 56:31.503, started processing at 56:31.503, thread #7
#5 finished processing at 56:48.504
Raised #9 at 56:48.504, started processing at 56:48.504, thread #4
#6 finished processing at 56:49.504
Raised #10 at 56:49.504, started processing at 56:49.504, thread #5
```

Мы видим, что события (с точки зрения пользователя) начинают просто пропадать. Поэтому допускать исчерпания пула потоков не стоит.

2) [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7). Здесь доставка событий происходит строго на пуле потоков, и возможен лишь один подписчик. Поведение в случае, когда обработка затягивается, такое же, как и для `System.Timers.Timer`: колбек запускается параллельно в разных потоках. Если пул потоков исчерпывается, то запуск откладывается до освобождения потока. Это соответствует вариантам #1 и #5 для `System.Timers.Timer`.

3) [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7). Здесь, наоборот, доставка событий возможна лишь в UI-поток. Подписчиков может быть сколько угодно, так что у нас возможны варианты #3 и #4. Длительные синхронные обработчики не перекрываются, а заставляют следующую доставку произойти позже. При этом события не накапливаются, а пропускаются: если остановить таймер, новые события не приходят. Это отличается от поведения `System.Timers.Timer`. Разница будет видна, если остановить таймер: для `System.Timers.Timer` отправленные события будут приходить и после остановки, пока все посланные события не отработают. А для `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` после остановки таймера события больше не придут.

Не забывайте, что делать длинную синхронную работу в UI-потоке не комильфо. Если ваш обработчик может продлиться аж до следующего тика, имеет смысл проводить обработку вне UI-потока.

4) [`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.7). Это аналог предыдущего таймера, но специально приспособленный для WPF. Так же, как и предыдущий таймер, он доставляет события в UI-поток, подписчиков также может быть сколько угодно, а события не накапливаются. (Значит, возможны лишь варианты #3 и #4.)

В отличие от `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, интервал до следующей отправки события отсчитывается не от момента предыдущей отправки, а от момента окончания всех (синхронных) обработчиков! Это значит, что если обработчик занимает больше времени, чем тик таймера, следующий обработчик будет вызван не сразу по окончанию предыдущего, а после интервала таймера.

---

Если вы хотите исключить одновременность работы, для таймеров из пула потоков нужно блокировать ресурс (например, при помощи `lock`). Для однопоточных синхронных таймеров блокировка, понятно, не нужна. Для асинхронных (`async void`) обработчиков вам понадобится асинхронная блокировка ([[1]](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock), [[2]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/)).

Comment: Спасибо. Такое подробное описание и сравнение различных таймеров я даже у Албахари не припомню.

Comment: @Bulson: И вам спасибо!

Comment: А с чем может быть связано срабатывание `throw new Exception("oops");`,  у меня Core i7 и все четыре ядра включены?

Comment: @Bulson: Если 4, то в порядке. А вот если вы укажете количество потоков меньше количества ядер, `SetMaxThreads` не сработает и будет исключение (проверка чисто экспериментальная, в документации ничего не нашёл).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.