# Разница в выбранном потоке между TaskCompletionSource и Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, tpl

С *практическим* асинхронным программированием столкнулся относительно недавно, и, изучая тему детальнее, назрел вопрос:

При создании задачи с помощью `Task.Factory.StartNew` (с параметром `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`) поток для задачи выбирается НЕ из пула.

Какой поток выбирается при создании с помощью `TaskCompletionSource` - из пула или не из пула?

---

**P.S.** Читал, мол, эти два способа эквивалентны... Но хочется разъяснтить очень важную деталь: какой поток выбирается при втором способе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакой.

`Task` — это не обязательно «код, бегущий в каком-то потоке». Это не абстракция над методом, бегущем непонятно где. Это лишь формальное обещание когда-либо предоставить результат. Работает ли над этим результатом один поток, несколько, или вообще ни одного — это внутренняя подробность, скрытая внутри `Task`'а, и недоступная наблюдателю.

Таски, создаваемые через `Task.Run` или `TaskFactory.CreateNew`, действительно являются методом, бегущим в том или ином потоке. Но это не является общим свойством *всех* тасков. Таск имеет право не бежать нигде.

Например, вы можете создать `TaskCompletionSource`, запустить таймер, и по приходу таймера завершить задачу. При этом, понятно, ваш таск *не будет бежать ни в каком потоке*.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Нет никакого потока](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/) (Stephen Cleary, перевод [Андрея Часовских](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha)).

Comment: Так ведь когда мы создаём Task, то эта задача будет выполнена в каком (в каких) либо потоке из пула. А как будет с TaskCompletionSource? Так же, но с "фишками" этого класса по поводу блокировок?

Comment: @khirnick: Обновил ответ, читайте.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Назрел вопрос: если мы создадим TaskCompletionSource и на SetResult поставим "длительную" функцию, то в каком потоке будет выполняться этот SetResult?

Comment: @khirnick: А что означает «на SetResult поставим "длительную" функцию»? Что значит «поставить функцию»?

Comment: @khirnick все методы `TaskCompletionSource` (и их продолжения) выполняются в текущем потоке, потому что это просто "обертка" над таском, никакого отношения к потокам не имеющая. Она нужна, например, там, где нужно выставить "новый" асинхронный АПИ при наличии "старого" (см. ответ sp7).

Comment: @andreycha понял. А если SetResult будет внутри таймера, то SetResult будет выполняться в потоке таймера? (про таймеры знаю, что они используют пул потоков)

Comment: @khirnick: Не все таймеры используют пул потоков, а некоторые используют, но не всегда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696486/10105

Comment: @VladD ого, спасибо больше. Очень интересно и подробно!

Comment: @khirnick: Пожалуйста! Рад, что пригодилось!

Answer (score 1):

Класс `TaskCompletionSource<T>` - это класс позволяющий создать задачу `Task`, которой вы управляете как марионеткой. Ее можно в любой момент сделать успешно завершившейся или записать в нее исключение и тем самым сказав, что она завершилась с ошибкой. Данный класс можно применять, например, при переводе с паттерна `IAsyncResult` на `TAP`.

```
 public static Task<IPHostEntry> GetHostEntryAsync(string hostNameOrAddress)
 {
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IPHostEntry>();
     Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress, asyncResult =>
     {
         try
         {
             IPHostEntry result = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(asyncResult);
             tcs.SetResult(result);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             tcs.SetException(e);
         }
    }, null);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```