# Запуск таймера в другом потоке

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Объясните пожалуйста почему не работает. На форме в `Load_Form` такой код:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            SetTimer();
        });
    }

    public void SetTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text += 1;
    }
```

Метод `timer_Tick` не срабатывает, почему?

Comment: а `Timer` у вас из какого пространства имён?

Comment: @4per  `System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: уберите 'await Task.Run(() =>'.

Comment: Вот тут есть про поведение различных таймеров: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696486/10105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) не поддерживает использование из нескольких потоков. Об этом явно написано в документации:

> ... This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.

В зависимости от ситуации можете попробовать:

- Использовать другие таймеры, например [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) или [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Создавать и запускать таймер из потока пользовательского интерфейса.