# Чем инициировать события изменения времени в миллисекундах с повышенной точностью?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, таймер

Какие есть методы вызова события в программе на VB.NET/С# с повышенной точностью?
Нужно обрабатывать данные по точным заданным меткам времени и так что бы событие успевало обрабатываться быстро (скорее всего асинхронно).

Comment: Что значит с "повышенной точностью"? На сколько-то процентов лучше чем нейтивные события дотнета в рамках одного железа? Что конкретно не устраивает в точности событий шарпа что им ищется замена? С чего вообще растет идея о том, что у событий будет какая-нибудь значимая задержка? Как можно утверждать что-то про время на обработку данных если мы не знаем что и как будет обрабатыватся и на каком железе? Ну прям очень странный вопрос... Советую его переформулировать.

Comment: Windows это не ОС реального времени. И никакие времена в Windows не гарантированы. Грубо говоря, если Windows начала (к примеру) процедуру свопинга, то все остальные процессы тормозятся до окончания этой процедуры. А сколько будет длится свопинг никто не знает. То же самое с дисковыми операциями, с сетевыми операциями.

Comment: @Andrew то есть мы тупо используем таймер на форме и все будет прекрасно работать и мы точно сможем отследить например наступление времени 00:00: +100 миллисекунд?  Замена шарпу в вопросе не искалась как бы, это уже ваша выдумка.

Comment: Какой именно таймер? В стандартном дотнете их минимум три.

Comment: Таки вопрос и в том что именно лучше использовать...........

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь 100ms? то есть требуется точность в 1/10 секунды? И в чем проблема? при помощи любых стандартных средств и не допотопном железе получить такую точность?

Comment: Для чего использовать? События приходят в вашу программу извне или вы их должны генерировать? Насколько часто?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а я как бы и не в курсе могут ли они приходить из вне или они могут приходить с таймера на форме. Я просто знаю что есть таймер на форме и знаю что он тупит при долгой обработке данных в клиентском коде.

Comment: сделаем по-другому. Логируй время при помощи таймера каждые 100ms с точностью до миллисекунд. Паралельно логируй значения запущенного Stopwatch (он работает на тиках проца. Так ты сможешь сравнить несоответствие при вызове ивентов ни конкретно твоем железе и увидишь на сколько оно тебе лично подходит.  Через 1 минуту сохрани логи и просмотри что бы сделать выводы о точности. И да, запускай на релизе, а не на дебаге для чистоты теста. Так ты сможешь оценить скорость работы и дилей при вызове ивентов.

Comment: Понял. WinForms, используется `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. События этого таймера работают в GUI-потоке. Если они длительные, то форма замерзает и т. п. Тогда вам действительно нужно обрабатывать события асинхронно, в другом потоке.

Comment: К прошлому сообщению: Если же есть существенно большая задержка чем на полученных результах -- это значит что ты где-то набыдлокодил или же вызываешь долгоработающие методы в основном потоке или же используешь устаревшее железо. А совсем не то, что сама система ивентов медленная/имеет большие задержки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо посмотреть в сторону технологий Complex Event Processing (CEP).

Так, от Microsoft есть [StreamInsight](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=30149), но есть и другие.

Answer (score 0):

Нет таких методов, особенно асинхронно.

Comment: Можно узнать, в чем конкретно проблема вызова асинхронного метода по событию? Допустим вызов метода подписанного на событие вызывается исключительно синхронно (я не проверял, не знаю, возможно это так и есть), то если это так, то в чем проблема из этого синхронного  метода подписанного на ивент запустить таску, которая бы асинхронно решала задачу?

Comment: Я проверял. Можете убедиться: http://amsawa.narod.ru/data/Test_uDelay.rar. Там асинхронный вызов задержки выдаёт показательные результаты, а с синхронным всё как и ожидалось.

Answer (score 0):

> то есть мы тупо используем таймер на форме и все будет прекрасно работать и мы точно сможем отследить например наступление времени 00:00: +100 миллисекунд?

С этих слов делаем вывод что допустимая ошибка является 100ms. И со слов:

> Я просто знаю что есть таймер на форме и знаю что он тупит при долгой обработке данных в клиентском коде.

Делаем вывод что должен использоватся `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Пишем тестовую программу:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace TestWinFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer _tm = new Timer();
        Stopwatch _st = new Stopwatch();
        List<long> _log = new List<long>();
        long _lastElapsed = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
            _tm.Interval = 100;

            _st.Start();
            _tm.Start();
        }


        private void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _log.Add(_st.ElapsedMilliseconds - _lastElapsed - _tm.Interval);
            _lastElapsed = _st.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            if (_log.Count == 300)
            {
                string[] log = new[] { _log.Average().ToString() };

                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\TestLog.txt", log);
                MessageBox.Show("finish!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

У меня в лог записалось `9,71666666666667`, **что означает что точность работы таймера/вызова_ивента по даному таймеру в 10 раз выше требуемой, а значит искать замену ему нет нужды.**

Это же означает что если возникают проблемы у тебя на твоей задаче, то это:

- или проблема железа
- или проблема неоптимального кода. Например, того что данные обрабатываются в основном потоке, что тормозит сам таймер. И использовав любую другую реализацию ивентов ты получишь все те же самые проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Так как детальных требований нет, то могу предложить такой вариант, который решает проблему подвисания `UI` или ожидания выполнения прошлого вызова до возможности проверить настало ли время обработки следующего.

Если скорость выполнения метода может быть долгой, временные метки находятся очень близко друг к другу и они вызывают один и тот же код, то можно использовать класс из другого моего ответа, который позволяет игнорировать вызовы, если метод ещё не выполнился или ставить их в очередь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940044/185863

Если события не планируется добавлять в ходе работы программы, то `lock(...)` вообще можно убрать.

**EventInfo.cs**

```c#
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class EventInfo
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; }

        public EventInfo(DateTime time)
        {
            Time = time;
        }
    }
}
```

**EventManager.cs**

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Нужен лишь для того, чтобы при подписке в параметрах метода было автоматом EventInfo info,
    /// а не EventInfo obj, что избавляет от необходимости его переименовывать.
    /// </summary>
    public delegate void EventInfoHandler(EventInfo info);

    public class EventManager
    {
        private readonly object _sync;
        private readonly List<EventInfo> _events;
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;

        public event EventInfoHandler Triggered;

        public EventManager(bool captureCurrentSyncContext)
        {
            // Экземпляр текущего класса нужно создавать в UI потоке, чтобы событие Triggered
            // так же срабатывало в UI потоке, если это необходимо. Так же captureCurrentSyncContext
            // должен быть true
            if (captureCurrentSyncContext)
            {
                _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
            }
            else
            {
                // Контекст синхронизации пула потоков
                _syncContext = new SynchronizationContext();
            }

            _sync = new object();
            _events = new List<EventInfo>();
            _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        public async void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    while (!_cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        lock (_sync)
                        {
                            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                            for (int i = 0; i < _events.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (now >= _events[i].Time)
                                {
                                    OnTriggered(_events[i]);
                                    _events.RemoveAt(i);
                                    --i;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        await Task.Delay(50, _cancellation.Token);
                    }

                    _cancellation.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                _cancellation.Dispose();
                _cancellation = null;

                // Логируем, если нужно
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex); // Используем свой логгер, это просто пример
            }
        }

        // Для остановки 1 раз перед закрытие приложения
        public void Stop()
        {
            _cancellation.Cancel();
        }

        public void Add(EventInfo eventInfo)
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _events.Add(eventInfo);
            }
        }

        public void Add(IEnumerable<EventInfo> events)
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _events.AddRange(events);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Инициирует срабатывание события не дожидаясь его обработки у подписчиков.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info"></param>
        protected void OnTriggered(EventInfo info)
        {
            var handler = Triggered;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                // Отправляем уведомление о событии и забываем (асинхронно)
                _syncContext.Post((unused) =>
                {
                    handler.Invoke(info);
                }, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```c#
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static EventManager EventManager { get; private set; } 

        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }

        // Не придумал, как захватить контекст синхронизации UI создав 
        // экземпляр класса здесь.
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            if (EventManager != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            EventManager = new EventManager(true);
            EventManager.Triggered += OnEventManagerTriggered;
            EventManager.Add(new EventInfo(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)));
            EventManager.Add(new EventInfo(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8)));
            EventManager.Add(new EventInfo(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)));
            EventManager.Start();
        }

        private static void OnEventManagerTriggered(EventInfo info)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(info.Time.ToLongTimeString());
        }
    }
}
```

**MainForm.cs**

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnMainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program.Initialize();
            Program.EventManager.Triggered += OnEventManagerTriggered;
        }

        private void OnEventManagerTriggered(EventInfo info)
        {
            _listBox.Items.Add(info.Time.ToLongTimeString());
        }
    }
}
```