# Не работает многопоточность C#

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Методы по отдельности работают, но когда хочу выполнить их с помощь многопоточности ничего не происходит.

```
private void buttonFly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Operator operator1 = new Operator(pictureBoxQuad1, pictureBoxMehan1, this.Width, this.Height);
            Operator operator2 = new Operator(pictureBoxQuad2, pictureBoxMeh2, this.Width, this.Height);
            Thread myThread1 = new Thread(operator1.StartFly);
            Thread myThread2 = new Thread(operator2.StartFly);
            myThread1.Start();
            myThread2.Start();
        }

public class Operator
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
        Quadrocopter Quadrocopter;
        Mehanic1 Mehanic;
        PictureBox PictureBoxQuad;
        PictureBox PictureBoxMehan;

        public  Operator (PictureBox PictureBoxQuad, PictureBox PictureBoxMehan, int Width, int Height)
        {
            this.PictureBoxQuad = PictureBoxQuad;
            this.PictureBoxMehan = PictureBoxMehan;
            Quadrocopter = new Quadrocopter(Width, Height, PictureBoxQuad.Width, PictureBoxQuad.Height, PictureBoxQuad.Location); ;
            Mehanic = new Mehanic1();
            Quadrocopter.NotifyToFix += Mehanic.GoToFix;

            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Tick += MoveQuadrocopter;
        }

        public void StartFly()
        {
            timer.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }

        void MoveQuadrocopter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Quadrocopter.IsQuadracFault)
            {
                timer.Interval = 100;
                PictureBoxQuad.Location = Quadrocopter.Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Interval = 1000;
                PictureBoxMehan.Location = Quadrocopter.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: С данной проблемой нет . Не смотря на вашу помощь, все равно появлялись ошибки. Изменила саму логику программы, итоговая цель была достигнута.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете взаимодействовать с интерфейсом из стороннего потока. Точнее, как вы уже поняли, можете, но так работать не будет.

А вот так будет:

```cs
private void buttonFly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Operator operator1 = new Operator(pictureBoxQuad1, pictureBoxMehan1, this.Width, this.Height, this);
    Operator operator2 = new Operator(pictureBoxQuad2, pictureBoxMeh2, this.Width, this.Height, this);
    // ... ваш код
}
```

```cs
public class Operator
{
    // ...ваш код
    Form form;

    public Operator (PictureBox PictureBoxQuad, PictureBox PictureBoxMehan, int Width, int Height, Form form)
    {
        this.form = form;
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    void MoveQuadrocopter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Quadrocopter.IsQuadracFault)
        {
            timer.Interval = 100;
            Point location = Quadrocopter.Execute();
            form.Invoke((Action)(() => PictureBoxQuad.Location = location));
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            Point location = Quadrocopter.Execute();
            form.Invoke((Action)(() => PictureBoxMehan.Location = location));     
        }
    }
}
```

`Form.Invoke()` перенаправляет вызов в UI поток формы.

Еще я не уверен, будет ли `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` работать в многопоточной среде, если не будет, напишите, придумаем что-нибудь, есть и другие таймеры, и способы реализовать это без таймеров. Но чтобы понять, как правильно реализовать, надо выяснить, что там внутри у `Quadrocopter.Execute()`.

Comment: Эх, опять вы дубликаты не ищете...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ окей, а по поводу таймера? Я не уверен, что будет работать, но протестировать не имею возможности, так что может дубликат, а может и не совсем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кстати в том ответе я бы таки заменил `Task.Factory.StartNew` на `Task.Run`. И `LongRunning` там - весьма спорное использование, хотя на суть `async/await` это не влияет.

Comment: Если это проблема таймеров (судя по документации данный таймер работает только в UI потоке, тут кстати можно почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696486/220553)), то тогда у вас изначально неверный ответ, акцент которого идет именно на решение проблемы из "вопроса закрывашки" (дубликата), с добавлением неуверенного "будет ли таймер работать в многопоточности". Вы тогда уж определитесь на что давать ответ, ибо в таком виде это чистый дубликат, а если вы распишете про таймер и в конце добавите просто ссылку на дубликат и простой пример, то тут согласен, ок, дубликатом не будет.

Comment: По поводу "того ответа" - почему это адресовано мне? Ответ общий, любой может всегда его поправить/дополнить, дерзайте)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ потому что вы его рефите. Не совсем логично, чтобы я шел править ваши референсы.

Comment: Вы сейчас это серьезно? По правилам ресурса мы что должны сделать? Правильно, если на вопрос уже есть ответ, то мы **обязаны** поставить голос за закрытие как "дубликат" и без разницы от кого там ответ, без разницы как он написан, главное, чтобы решал поставленную задачу. На SO есть вопросы/ответы, которые были созданы специально в целях закрытия других однотипных вопросов на них, и тот вопрос является одним из них. Я вообще не отношусь к тому вопросу как либо, я просто знаю, что он есть и всегда аналогичные вопросы буду закрывать им, таковы правила... Так что о каком "рефите" идет речь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ давайте не будем в "кто умнее задвинет речь о мировой справдливости" играть, я всё равно психану и переверну стол раньше. Я всего-лишь показал на то, что увидел. Давайте теперь дружно и сознательно на это забьем. Всё верно, правила же есть, можно не думать своей головой.

Comment: Просто не делайте меня виноватым, как вы всегда это любите. Я понимаю, что вы тут готовы нарушать все порядки, лишь бы заработать репутации, но я же не говорю вам "удаляйте этот ответ!", нет, наоборот, я даже сказал, как лучше бы его было поправить, чтоб он имел хоть какую-либо пользу для SO. Вот и все, я лишь этого хочу, чистоту и полезность ресурса, не более. А вы мне тут говорите "вы его рефите". Ваше право конечно думать, как угодно, но правила есть правила, следуйте им! А репутация, как я вам говорил ранее - давайте буду лайкать все ваши ответы, но оно вам надо? Берите лучше качеством!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я обязательно поправлю ответ, примерно сразу как получу фидбэк от автора вопроса, не хочу гадать.